# Reading lines with spaces in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm supposed to read a text file line by line an extract three variables:

```
1- int index -> index of list
2- string name -> name of a person
3- string gift -> Christmas gift
```

An example:

```
1 Robert XBox360 Gaming Console 
2 Harold Dress Shirt
```

So for the first line, `index = 1 , name = Robert , gift = XBox360 Gaming Console`

This is what I have been doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("giftlist.txt");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int index;
        std:: string name, gift;
        if (!(iss >> index >> name >> gift)) { break; } // error

        std::cout << index << " "<< name << " " << gift << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 Robert XBox360
```

So it does not read the rest of the gift line, it stops at white space (`i.e gift = XBox360`). How can I fix this to read the rest of the gift name? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the name is always in a single word as well as if white spaces are always spaces (or if it's okay to replace them as such). Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
    std:: string name, gift, more;
    if (!(iss >> index >> name >> gift)) { break; } // error
    while (iss >> more) { gift += " "+more; }
```

But if name could be "John Smith" then you are out of luck in determining where the name ends and the gift starts.